# 2010: Refinement Panel ignores custom xml

Tags: 2010, refinement-panel

I have the following xml pasted into the Filter Category Definition in the refinement section. Also, Use Default Configuration is unchecked. No matter what I do though the default Refinement options are always shown instead of my custom filter. What am I missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FilterCategories>
    <Category 
        Title="Department" 
        Description="Use this filter to restrict results to a specific department" 
        Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator" 
        MetadataThreshold="5"
        NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="4"
        MaxNumberOfFilters="20"
        SortBy="Frequency"
        SortByForMoreFilters="Name"
        SortDirection="Descending"
        SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending"
        ShowMoreLink="True"
        MappedProperty="DepartmentRefinement"
        MoreLinkText="show more"
        LessLinkText="show fewer" />
</FilterCategories>
```

Comment: Are you looking at an unpublished version of the page (content approval enabled) ?

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with the XML! Are you removing the OOTB filter and pasting this one instead? Or are adding your filter to the default filters?

Comment: I'm removing what's there and pasting in this. Also I've definitely checked it in, saved it, and published it.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me ... check my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FilterCategories>
  <Category    Title="Format"    Description="The file extension of the item"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="5"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="4"    MaxNumberOfFilters="0"    SortBy="Frequency"    SortDirection="Descending"    SortByForMoreFilters="Name"    SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending"     ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="FileExtension"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer">
    <CustomFilters MappingType="ValueMapping" DataType="String" ValueReference="Absolute" ShowAllInMore="False">
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Adobe PDF">
        <OriginalValue>pdf</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Email">
        <OriginalValue>eml</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>msg</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>exch</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Excel">
        <OriginalValue>odc</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>ods</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>xls</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>xlsb</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>xlsm</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>xlsx</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Image">
        <OriginalValue>tif</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>tiff</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Lotus Notes">
        <OriginalValue>nsf</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="OneNote">
        <OriginalValue>one</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="PowerPoint">
        <OriginalValue>odp</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>ppt</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>pptm</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>pptx</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Publisher">
        <OriginalValue>pub</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Text">
        <OriginalValue>odt</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>txt</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>url</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>csv</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Visio">
        <OriginalValue>vdw</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vdx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vsd</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vss</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vst</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vsx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vtx</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Webpage">
        <OriginalValue>ascx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>asp</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>aspx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>htm</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>html</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>jhtml</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>js</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>mht</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>mhtml</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>mspx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>php</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue></OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="XML">
        <OriginalValue>xml</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Word">
        <OriginalValue>doc</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>docm</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>docx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>dot</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>nws</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Zip">
        <OriginalValue>zip</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
    </CustomFilters>
  </Category>
  <Category   Title="File Category"             Description="Use this filter to restrict results by Category"                           Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="1"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="3"    MaxNumberOfFilters="0"    SortBy="Name"    SortByForMoreFilters="Name"    SortDirection="Ascending"    SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="FileFormat"    MoreLinkText="Show more"    LessLinkText="Show fewer"   />
</FilterCategories>
```